# Mapping with extendend class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, conform

I'm using NHibernate with [ConfORM](http://code.google.com/p/codeconform/) to map my domain entities.

Assuming the following classes:

```
public class Event {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
}

public class EventA : Event {
    public virtual string PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class EventB : Event {
    public virtual string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Diagram]

I need **not repeat** NHibernate tables fields in derived classes, but uses the base class, as in the diagram.

My ConfORM setup :

```
var domainAssembly = typeof(Event).Assembly;
var domainEntities = from t in domainAssembly.GetTypes() where t==typeof(Event) select t;
var orm = new ObjectRelationalMapper();
orm.Patterns.Sets.Add(new UseSetWhenGenericCollectionPattern());
orm.Patterns.PoidStrategies.Add(new ConfOrm.Patterns.IdentityPoidPattern());
orm.TablePerConcreteClass(domainEntities);
var patternsAppliers = new CoolPatternsAppliersHolder(orm);
var mapper = new Mapper(orm, patternsAppliers);
[...]
```

Any ideas on how to approach the problem could?

Answer (score 0):

exchange `orm.TablePerConcreteClass(domainEntities);` with `orm.TablePerClass(domainEntities);` which will create

```
Event
-----
PK | Id

EventA
-----
PK,FK | EventId
```

because a seperate Id column in EventA is not nessesary